# Catching errors when loading images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, error-handling

**EDIT 2:** It's also come to my attention that there *is* no "best" way to deal with this problem; it depends on the needs of the application. I would just delete this post, but I have to imagine that at some point someone will have a similar question. Thanks to @Pointy for helping me out.

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to @Pointy for explaining the problem with my code as is below. Accordingly, my question has now changed. Since using a `try`/`catch` block is not going to help me, what's the best way to handle a missing/unavailable/whatever image file?

---

I'm trying to find a way to handle missing image files in my scripts. The images are `Image` objects. I'm using exclusively vanilla JS. Consider the following code:

```
try {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'badpath.jpeg';

  img.onerror = function() {
    throw new Error('unable to load URL: ' + img.src);  
  };
}

catch (e){
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

The code never makes it to the catch block. It throws the error but it never makes it to the `catch` block. Why is this?

Comment: When the error handler is actually called (that is, when the browser decides it can't load the image), the `try ... catch` is finished already. Throwing an exception from inside an event handler will never do anything useful.

Comment: @Pointy : Okay, that makes sense. So I suppose my new question becomes this: What's the best way to handle missing image files?

Comment: Well what is it that you want to do when the image isn't available? Notify the user? You could add a message to the page, or log something on the console, or something else appropriate. There's no "best" way.

Comment: @Pointy I see what you mean. I'll have to figure it out on a case-by-case basis. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The answer to the question is: "The best way is to set an onerror handler on the image object, not by throwing an exception because the error happens asynchronously"